# Service becomes null after injecting in DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a service CurrenUserServce that works perfectly. But when i inject it in DbContext, suddennly UserId is always null in my Controllers.

```
public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.UserId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    }
    public string UserId { get; private set; }
}
```

My DbContext looks like this

```
 public class AppDbContext:IdentityDbContext<AppUser>,IAppDbContext
{
    private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options, ICurrentUserService currentUserService):base(options)
    {
        _currentUserService = currentUserService;
    }
```

DbContext is registered as scoped and the service is registered as singleton, i also tried scoped and transient in service but didnt work.

Comment: `CurrentUserService` definitely needs to be `Scoped` or `Transient`, it can never be `Singleton`... wonder how you even got it to work like that.

Comment: Thank  you. I tried Transient, now its working, but not working with Scoped.

Comment: Not working with Scoped... It's weird. Can you show the method `Startup.ConfigureServices`?

Comment: CurrentUserService would work as singleton if the user wasn't resolved in the constructor, and was instead resolved when the property is accessed.

Comment: @Llama which, essentially, gives you scoped service disguised as singleton. No point of doing that, and probably not possible via .NET Core default DI.

Comment: @Llama OMG Thank you! That was the bug on my code. Without changing that part of my code the service is null in the DbContext regardless if it is scoped or transient.

Comment: @Dusan it's possible because `IHttpContextAccessor` itself is registered as singleton: [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8b30d862de6c9146f466061d51aa3f1414ee2337/src/Http/Http/src/HttpServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L27)

Answer (score 0):

The bug on my code was this:

```
public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    this.UserId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
}
public string UserId { get; private set; }
```

I changed it as @Llama pointed out.

```
 private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string UserId => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

Regardless whether the service was scope or transient, the service is null in the DbContext until i corrected the code in CurrentUserService.